# is it possible to add multiple selectors in a delegate function in jquery?

Tags: jquery, delegates

Something like creating a namespace/sub-module for my scripts concerning a module in my app? Like say I only want to delegate certain tasks to elements inside a certain div like say #submodule1.

Can I do something like this:

```
 $("#submodule1")
    .delegate(".selector1", "click", function() {} )
    .delegate(".selector2", "click", function() {} )
```

And if it is possible, will it be the same as:

```
 $("#submodule1").delegate(".selector1", "click", function() {} )
 $("#submodule1").delegate(".selector2", "click", function() {} )
```

**EDIT**

based on T.J. Crowder's answer i should be able to do this:

```
$("#soap-test-test-cases")
  .delegate(".soap-test-case", "click", function(){
      testfunction();
  });
  .delegate("legend", "click", function() {
    alert("this is a test!");
  });
```

but i get a syntax error

Comment: Syntax error: Remove the semi-colon after at the end of the first `});`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Edit**:

Your edit changes the question, now you have a syntax error:

```
$("#soap-test-test-cases")
   .delegate(".soap-test-case", "click", function(){
       testfunction();
   });
// v--- here
   .delegate("legend", "click", function() {
     alert("this is a test!");
   });
```

If you remove the semicolon in front of it, you're fine:

```
$("#soap-test-test-cases")
   .delegate(".soap-test-case", "click", function(){
       testfunction();
   })  // <== No semi here, we're not done with the statement yet
   .delegate("legend", "click", function() {
     alert("this is a test!");
   }); // <== Now we're done with the statement
```

That's **one statement** spread across multiple lines, which is fine. You're calling `$()`, then calling `delegate` on the object that `$()` returns, then calling `delegate` on the object that your first call to `delegate` returns.

With the semicolon after the first `delegate` call, you have **two** statements, and the second one starts with a `.` (which is a syntax error).

JavaScript mostly doesn't care about line breaks, it cares about *statements*, which are terminated by semicolons. It has the horror that is *automatic semicolon insertion*, but it won't insert semicolons that make your code invalid. (It *will* insert semicolons that make your code *misbehave*, though, so again, know where your statements begin and end and make sure you're providing the correct semicolons.)

---

**Original answer**:

The code samples you've given are both valid, and they have the same effect: Hooking up two separate functions to handle clicks, one of them on one subset of elements (`.selector1`) and the other on the other (`.selector2`). Your first example is just standard chaining.

I don't *think* this is what you're asking, but just in case: If you want to use the *same* function for both classes of elements, you can do that, too:

```
$("#submodule1").delegate(".selector1, .selector2", "click", function() { });
```

...or (of course) use the same named function with two separate `delegate` calls.

Comment: wow so having a page of $("#submodule1"), $("#submodule2") and a lot of delegates in them is the "accepted" better practice?

Comment: hmm i tried the first one but it doesn't work for me. won't line breaks break the code? will edit the question to show the code

Comment: @corroded: I didn't say it was best practice, I said you can do it. :-) But if you have a page with a defined area within which you want to handle clicks on any element, that's exactly what `delegate` is for.

Comment: @corroded: The line breaks you've shown are fine -- [try this](http://jsbin.com/oyufe5), [and this](http://jsbin.com/oyufe5/2), but definitely add a semicolon to the end of the *statement*. **Never** rely on automatic semicolon insertion.

Comment: @corroded: Your edit changed the question, but you weren't to know that. :-) I've updated to answer the update.